# Changing the display of the report from Virus Total API

Tags: php, html, api

Currently I am working on a website that involves scanning urls contained in database through the Virus Total PHP API. Currently all of this works correctly, however I was hoping that there was a way to display the report that is generated graphically rather than just code. The code I am using with the virus total API is:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "apps";

$inputappname = $_POST["appname"];
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die ("Failed to connect...");
$query = "select * from data where name = '$inputappname'";
$sqlResult = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

mysqli_close($conn);

require_once('VirusTotalApiV2.php');
$api = new VirusTotalAPIV2('VirustotalAPIKey');


/* Displaying database */
if($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlResult)){
    echo 'Search: '; echo $inputappname; echo '<br><br>';

    for($i = 0; $i < 31; $i++){
        $array = array(
            $i => $data[$i]         
        );
    echo $array[$i];    echo "<br>";
    }

    $searchUrl = $data[11];

    /* Displaying security results */
    $report = $api->getURLReport($searchUrl);
    $api->displayResult($report);
    print($api->getTotalNumberOfChecks($report) . '<br>');
    print($api->getNumberHits($report) . '<br>');
    print($api->getReportPermalink($report, FALSE) . '<br>');

} else {
    header('Location: notinlist.php');
}
?>
```

The result that is returned currently looks like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [permalink] =>     https://www.virustotal.com/url/dc2a27ec0e08d9c6eddd61411ab422c0e23cfc75d00bbd5db19ca9d3e8c53fa2/analysis/1430547959/
    [resource] => https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en
    [url] => https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en
    [response_code] => 1
    [scan_date] => 2015-05-02 06:25:59
    [scan_id] => dc2a27ec0e08d9c6eddd61411ab422c0e23cfc75d00bbd5db19ca9d3e8c53fa2-1430547959
    [verbose_msg] => Scan finished, scan information embedded in this object
    [filescan_id] => 
    [positives] => 0
    [total] => 63
    [scans] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CLEAN MX] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [VX Vault] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [ZDB Zeus] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Tencent] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [MalwarePatrol] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [ZCloudsec] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [PhishLabs] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => unrated site
                )

            [Zerofox] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [K7AntiVirus] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Quttera] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Spam404] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [AegisLab WebGuard] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [MalwareDomainList] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                    [detail] => http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php?search=play.google.com
                )

            [ZeusTracker] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                    [detail] => https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/monitor.php?host=play.google.com
                )

            [zvelo] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Google Safebrowsing] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Kaspersky] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [BitDefender] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Dr.Web] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [ADMINUSLabs] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [C-SIRT] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [CyberCrime] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Websense ThreatSeeker] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [CRDF] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Webutation] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Trustwave] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Web Security Guard] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [G-Data] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Malwarebytes hpHosts] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Wepawet] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [AlienVault] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Emsisoft] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Malc0de Database] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                    [detail] => http://malc0de.com/database/index.php?search=play.google.com
                )

            [SpyEyeTracker] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                    [detail] => https://spyeyetracker.abuse.ch/monitor.php?host=play.google.com
                )

            [malwares.com URL checker] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Phishtank] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Malwared] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Avira] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [OpenPhish] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Antiy-AVL] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [SCUMWARE.org] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [FraudSense] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Opera] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Comodo Site Inspector] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Malekal] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [ESET] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Sophos] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => unrated site
                )

            [Yandex Safebrowsing] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                    [detail] => http://yandex.com/infected?l10n=en&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en
                )

            [SecureBrain] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Malware Domain Blocklist] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Blueliv] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Netcraft] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => unrated site
                )

            [PalevoTracker] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [AutoShun] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => unrated site
                )

            [ThreatHive] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [ParetoLogic] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Rising] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [URLQuery] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => unrated site
                )

            [StopBadware] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => unrated site
                )

            [Sucuri SiteCheck] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Fortinet] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [ZeroCERT] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

            [Baidu-International] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detected] => 
                    [result] => clean site
                )

        )

)
63
0
https://www.virustotal.com/url/dc2a27ec0e08d9c6eddd61411ab422c0e23cfc75d00bbd5db19ca9d3e8c53fa2/analysis/
```

Is there any way to change this to be displayed graphically?

Comment: I have created a simple UI for this exact purpose using Laravel + JQuery. This is currently for files and hashes, but can easily be replicated for URLs. The output is classified into two tabs for each positive scans and negatives. Take a look at the [screenshot](https://snag.gy/s41eR6.jpg) to see if it fits your needs